# Question Regarding External Jars and MAVEN

Tags: gwt, jar, maven

I have two GWT  projects Project A and Project B.The dependencies of these projects  are taken care by MAVEN.Project B depends on Project A ,and this part is already taken care of.

Now i need to add an external Jar into Project A.I do not want to use Maven for this .I just want to add the external jar file into Project A and update my ProjectA.gwt.xml to inherit the jar.

So i included the jar file in Project A.But Project B was not recognizing the classes in the jar.So i went ahead and followed the following steps

1) Right Clicked on Project A and selected Build Path
2) Click on Configure Build Path
3) Order and Export the jar file

Then after doing so ,my Project B could compile the classes used from the JAR file.But at Runtime its crashing.Its not able to recognize the classes from the JAR file.

Can anyone provide me what to do on this?
Please provide me solution with/without using MAVEN.I would prefer without using MAVEN.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you prefer not using Maven? And when you say you right-clicked, which tool are you referring to? Eclipse maybe?

Comment: Oh ya its eclipse.Sorry for not mentioning that.I can even use maven but i am not able to add the external libs to my poms

Answer (score 2):

I think you should keep all the dependency management in Maven.

The Eclipse Maven plugin manage the Build Path Configuration of your Eclipse project, it should be not modified manually.

You could use this configuration to add external librairies to the repository  :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>deploy-on-local-repo1</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <file>src/your-librairie.jar</file>
                <groupId>com.yourlibrairiegroupID</groupId>
                <artifactId>librairie-name</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Hope it will fix your problem.

Comment: This works, but I am routinely amazed that Mavenites don't understand this usecase better. If you are on a distributed team, and need anyone, on any local repo to be able to build a project that uses a open source dependency (i.e. Google Code project), which does not happen to be on a public Maven repo, then you'll need to be adding external jars that are kept in your SVN. Simply adding jars to a local or enterprise repo manually does not make an automated build that can run on any CI machine.